# Why is position broken after applying js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

why does other images "jump" down after clicking on some image(applying js)?
http://almaweby.cz/reference.html
Try to click on first image.. text about it will slide down,that´s correct and then other images jump down..How can I rewrite the code to move down only next row and not the first?

And a bit offtopic. Why is second row moved differently than the first one?

Here is a sample of my problem
https://jsfiddle.net/ytLqgk0v

```js
$('.hook').on('click', function( evt ) {
 $(evt.currentTarget).find('.popis').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.hook{
width: 30%;
margin-right: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
.nahledy{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hook">
  <div class="nahledy"></div>
  <div class="popis" style="display: none;">
    <p><b>LOrem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hook">
    <div class="nahledy"></div>
  <div class="popis" style="display: none;">
    <p><b>Lorem ipsum again</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hook">
    <div class="nahledy"></div>
  <div class="popis" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum for third time</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

`

Comment: Please create a minimal, verifiable example of just the problem - don't just link to your site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Once you change code in that link, or that link gets removed from site,  it renders this question useless in the future. Questions should be self contained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flexbox for alignment instead of just having things float. To start, add `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent container and then clean up the position from there.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: That´s brilliant..thanks a lot... now I just have to find out why it is little moved(why it isn´t below itself)